# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Tutorial (Like Nerd Dinner)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Are there any tutorials like [Nerd Dinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) but for MVC 2.0? I've seen [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) but I'd prefer something that moves a little more swiftly.

If not, are there any reccomendations for more advanced tutorials that go over specific topics?

Side note: I really liked the style of the [NetTuts CodeIgniter Series](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-security/). Something like that but for ASP.NET MVC 2.0 would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete and quite advanced (technically) website develop with asp.net mvc 2.0: [Who Can Help Me?](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/) To find out more about it I suggest you read blogs of the authors.

Comment: The second sentence says that it is for MVC 1.0, has it been upgraded since then?

Answer (score 2):

NerdDinner has also been updated for ASP.NET MVC 2 and runs on ASP.NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 in the updated version of the book.

The updated source code is available on CodePlex: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

The updated book is available at... stores :)